# Windows 10-Ubuntu 19.10 dual boot installation halted, what to do?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10, 19.10

I am trying to install Ubuntu 19.10 alongside windows. I booted from my live USB (with Ubuntu OS) and selected the *Install Ubuntu* option from GRUB.

I've been stuck on this screen for the past ~20 minutes. What should I do?  It's my first time dual booting so I'm slightly concerned.

Thanks for the help in advance.

I've attached an image link of my screen.

[Current screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5hwQ.jpg)

Comment: Looks like Ubuntu halted when trying to calculate free space available. Was the drive in your system formatted by Windows as Dynamic? Ubuntu can't work with Dynamically partitioned drives.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didn't fiddle with the drives that much. I created a partition for Ubuntu OS,as I have done in the past using the Windows 'create partition..' settings. Should I wait until it un-halts?  Do I have any options to save my machine and data at this stage?

Comment: Can't say with certainty; no double-your-money-back guarantees here. But, by now, were it me, I would shut down and restart.